# How to create a file containing struct

Tags: c

I want control class, struct or something with new file. But when I create it. I can't run my program. This is my program:
`main` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "testing.h"

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        struct test var;
        var.a = 2;
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

file header struct:

```
#ifndef TESTING_H
#define TESTING_H

     struct test x;

#endif /* TESTING_H *
```

and last is file define struct:

```
typedef struct test {
    int a;
};
```

I do not have much experience in creating new file. May be my question is dumb. Hope everybody help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: @Petr, there is no .cpp file involved. Look at the code, it's [tag:c].

Comment: The struct definition has to be in the header file for this to work.

Comment: Replace `struct test x;` with your structure definition: `typedef struct...`

Comment: can you post all the files in their entirety please?  What you've posted is missing a trailing / on the (sub-line) multi line comment block.  Also, we need to see the build command if possible, and definitely the error code your'e getting.  What you've pasted here is like walking into an auto repair shop and saying, " I have a 2003 honda accord, what's wrong with it?"  We don't know what's happening when you run your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem "*I am guessing*" is the structure defintion

```
typedef struct test {
    int a;
};
```

This is not just a structure definition, but a type definition and it's missing the type name, it can be fixed like this

```
typedef struct test {
    int a;
} MyTestStruct;
```

or simply remove the `typedef` and just use `struct test` to declare instances of it.

Also, if you intend to access it's members then you must provide a definition in the same compilation unit where you access it's members, in this case in the "*main*" file as you called it.

If you want to hide the members (*make it an opaque structure*), try like this

**struct.h**

```
#ifndef __STRUCT_H__
#define __STRUCT_H__
struct test; // Forward declaration

struct test *struct_test_new();
int struct_test_get_a(const struct test *const test);
void struct_test_set_a(struct test *test, int value);
void struct_test_destroy(struct test *test);

#endif /* __STRUCT_H__ */
```

And you would then have

**struct.c**

```
#include "struct.h"

// Define the structure now
struct test {
    int a;
};

struct test *
struct_test_new()
{
    struct test *test;
    test = malloc(sizeof(*test));
    if (test == NULL)
        return NULL;
    test->a = DEFAULT_A_VALUE;
    return test;
}

int 
struct_test_get_a(const struct test *const test)
{
    return test->a;
}

void 
struct_test_set_a(struct test *test, int value)
{
    test->a = value;
}

void 
struct_test_destroy(struct test *test)
{
    if (test == NULL)
        return; 
    // Free all freeable members of `test'
    free(test);
}
```

This technique is actually very elegant and has many advantages, the most important being that you can be sure that the structure is used correctly since no one can set the values directly and hence no one can set invalid/incorrect values. And also, if some of it's members are allocated dynamically using `malloc()` you can ensure that they are freed when the user calls `_destroy()` on the pointer. You can control the range of values that you consider are appropriate, and avoid buffer overflows in cases where it applies.

Comment: I can do it in only file header. But I want use file .c or .cpp for more program bigger. So how to do it? Or can't do it with struct?

Comment: I don't understand, if you want to hide the members from the user you can create accessor functions, for example `int struct_test_get_a(const struct test *const test) {return test->a;};` and you can have a `struct_test_set_a(struct test *test, int value) {test->a = value;}` to set it. And then use pointers to the struct instance instead of instances.

Comment: May be my level not enough to understand your code. Anyway thank a lot. I will trying to your level. :D

Comment: I strongly agree, this is my prefered technique as well for handling "objects" in C.  I wouldn't call it elegant per se ( I miss the object context of an OO language ) but it works, and keeps your code for interraction in a good spot.  If you replace floating functions with function pointers in your struct -well then, you're darn close to having object methods but they sadly stil don't know which struct the functions "belong to", so I've never bothered.